# Html and php mysql friends system

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok I need help. I need to have a friends system in my website but i don't wont a lot of tables on my server.
In this friends system you can send request and they can accept or reject it? 
I can get the friends to send a request but i need away of Getting all of the users friends?

So i can talk to all my friends on my site and if they are not my friend i can not chat to them?

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's pointless to tell you how to build "the friends system" if you aren't comfortable with PHP and database design.

Comment: To me, this sounds like "hai guise i dont know hpw t0 do this stuff with PhP so yeah can you guise rite this f0r me? thankssssssssssssss"

Comment: well i kinda know a bit about about it i know how to make a login,register and others? and i am comfortable it makes website making alot easier i started to learn like 10 days ago but i guess im still in the beginner stage or maybe a bit more of mysql and php?

Comment: If you've started 10 days ago, you have a long ways to go buddy.

Comment: @esqew http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: yer i know nedd to learn a bit more and will

Comment: @Ryan In all seriousness, this question is very poorly written and broad.  Please consider revising it to be more specific about what you need help with.  If need be, open multiple targeted questions rather than one very broad one.

Comment: on your site (grubber): you need a closing tags for <option value="2010">2010 and <p1><p2><p2><footer> html tags dont exist, use class="" or id="" within a <p> <div> tags to define css styling.

Comment: yer im getting rid of da footers just using classes

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone You dont really need closing tags for <option value="2010">2010 because it all ready has one and i founf it on a website and its da same on facebook?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: Actually, `<footer>` is part of HTML5. But those other ones don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make 1 table in mysql "Friends"
Each friend request would INSERT INTO `Friends` 2 users (the requester and the requestee) and then you can have another colum called accepted which can be 0 or 1 (0=default/pending) (1=accepted).
You'll have to notify the requestee somehow, if they accept you turn `accepted` to 1 **and add a friend request `from` the requestee with accepted ==1**, and if they reject you can delete that row.
I'm sure theres a much more effecient way to do it, but as far as simplicity I think that's about as simple as it gets.

to get the friends of user A? just check the database for all `FROM` friends where `accepted` == 1

Comment: yer i thought it would be like that? but how would you go for a list of friends?

Comment: to get the friends of user A? actually how about you just also have accepting a friend make a friend request (in the database) with the from and to users swapped. It will have duplicate data, but this way you can just check the database for all `FROM` friends where `accepted` == 1

Comment: Yer i can get the users name and all the others?

Comment: yer but if i have multiple people on my site for instance                                                                 if i had bob send a friend request to fred and then Greg logged on and he wasnt friends of bob and fred wouldn't it show that all of the people are friends?

Answer (score 2):

Implement it as a directed graph, i.e. have a table that represents links between users (excuse my poor understanding of applying UML to databse design):

```
--------------------------------------
| Relation                           |
--------------------------------------
| id : UUID PRIMARY_KEY              |
| from : UUID INDEX(RELATION_FROM)   |
| to : UUID INDEX(RELATION_TO)       |
| status : ENUM("PENDING", "FORMED") |
--------------------------------------
```

Should be pretty straightforward to get code working for it (if not, you probably need to learn PHP and MySQL first ;).

---

As for the queries you need to execute, they're fairly straightforward:

```
SELECT * FROM relations WHERE from = ? AND status = "FORMED"; -- for getting all the friends of a user
SELECT * FROM relations WHERE from = ? AND status = "PENDING"; -- for getting all the pending friends of a user
```

Comment: I believe your queries are incomplete. If user A friends B, and B accepts, then when we look for B's friends, we won't find A. because B is not in the from

Comment: I was assuming they were unidirectional relations (too much Twitter), but I guess you could amend the queries to find links in either direction. But then again, the relations would look funny.